# oAuth uStream API

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm trying to get data from uStream using their API and oAuth.  I can get the auth token and that token does work in Rest API Client and I can get data. I however cannot get data in my project... I keep getting 401 unauth..

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.ustream.tv/oauth2/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials&=", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        IRestResponse<TokenObject> response2 = (IRestResponse<TokenObject>)client.Execute<TokenObject>(request);

        var tknName = response2.Data.access_token;

        GetData(tknName);
    }

        public void GetData(string token)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.ustream.tv/channels/206844441.json");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer" + token);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        IRestResponse jsonResponse = client.Execute(request);

        IRestResponse<Channel> json2Response2 = (IRestResponse<Channel>)client.Execute<Channel>(request);

        var blah = json2Response2.Content;
    }
```

The jsonResponse comes back 401... but I can use the token in API client like Insomnia and it will work... I can get data.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `token` is not prefixed with a single space, then this line:

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer" + token);
```

Should instead be (**added a space after Bearer**):

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

---

Additionally, the `GET` request for data does not require the `Content-Type` header to be added to the request; although including is unlikely to cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

As João mentioned, the main problem will be the missing space character between the string "Bearer" and the token itself . After you fix this i'm pretty sure it will work.
Yes, Content-Type is superfluous for GET request, but it does not harm the success of your request.

In addition, you don't need to provide client secret twice. That's enough to provide it through the Authorization header or the client_secret property in the request body.

So, that's enough to provide the secret that way:

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Ant in this case you shouldn't provide the secret again in the request body, here's the modified call, based on the original code:

```
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials&=", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Could you add some code to make your answer more clear?

Answer (score 0):

There were actually two things I had wrong.  First one pointed out by @João Angelo was the missing space between the string: Bearer & token.

Second and most frustrating was that authorization needed to be Authorization... with the capital A.  Now it works... .Thanks for the help.